# FindMaximum showing unexpected behaviour (bug?)

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am using `FindMaximum` to find the maxima and maximum value of a simple function $\sqrt{3-x^2}$ as follows:

```
FindMaximum[{(3-x^2)^(1/2), {1<x<4}}, {x,1}]
```

I don't get any answer and the code slowly consumes all my RAM (8 GB; usually it runs as about 3-4 GB) and just keeps on running. But, instead, if I modify the function to `(3-x^2)^1` then the code runs and gives the expected `{2., {x -> 1.}}`.

```
FindMaximum[{(3-x^2)^1, {1<x<4}}, {x,1}]
```

So, I tried `(3-x^2)^2` instead, thinking that the square root might be an issue but even this function just keeps on running forever and eats up all my RAM slowly. In fact any other power that tried just kept on running forever and slowly consuming all my RAM.

On the other hand if I try `FindMaximum[{(x^2-3)^(1/2), {1<x<4}}, {x,4}]` I get the expected `{3.60555, {x -> 4.}}`.

I am not sure what the issue is here. I have closed Mathematica, restarted my computer and stuff and this issue still persists. Every other code seems to be working as expected. Thanks.

EDIT: I am using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10 Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.746.

Comment: Works fine on *Mathematica* 12.2 and 10.4 (Windows 10).

Comment: I have _Mathematica_ 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10 Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.746. Do you have any other ideas for what this could be?

Comment: Works for me on MMa 12.1.1.0. Win10

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I see. I restarted my computer _again_ just in case, but it still persists...Please let me know if you guys have any other ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Well, whaddya know.  I tried it on 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10 and can duplicate the issue.  I guess you need a newer or older version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Wow...That is disgusting. That such a simple function would have such a bug. This is a bug, right? Thanks, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = (3 - x^2)^(1/2);
```

The problem appears to arise because the function is not real throughout the region specified by the constraint `1 < x < 4`. Change the constraint to

```
dom = FunctionDomain[{f[x], 1 < x < 4}, x]

(* 1 < x <= Sqrt[3] *)

max = FindMaximum[{f[x], dom}, {x, 1}]

(* {1.41421, {x -> 1.}} *)
```

For comparison,

```
Maximize[{f[x], 1 < x < 4}, x]

(* Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a result on the boundary will be returned.

{Sqrt[2], {x -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: I tried doing that too, but the problem still persists. Also, as I mentioned in the question, I tried with power 2 (making the function real) instead of 1/2 due to this reason, and the problem still persists. To be clear, it doesn't throw nay errors, but just keeps on running forever consuming all RAM. It seems @JimB was able to reproduce this issue with _Mathematica_ 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10 (see his comment under the question).